# how to assign value to a ListView with extjs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, extjs

i have a datatable and i want to show it's information in listview this is my code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Fname");
dt.Columns.Add("Lname");
dt.Rows.Add("mehdi", "nine");
Ext.Net.Store st = new Ext.Net.Store();
Store.Config cn = new Store.Config();
cn.DataSource = dt;

Store1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
Store1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
ListView1.DataBind();
```

but it doesn't show any thing! what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

1. You declare a data table with columns (`dt`) but you don't add any rows to it.
2. You declare `st` and don't use it at all. What's the purpose?
3. You declare `cn` and instantiate it and assign `dt` as it's datasource; yet `dt` has no rows.
4. Apparently you have a `ListView1` somewhere and you call `DataBind()`; however, is not clear what or where is the data source and whether you are filling it or not.
5. Similarly for `Store1`: What is it? You assign a SqlDataSource to it but you don't call the `Select` method of the SqlDataSource so it's not clear how's the data going to be selected.

In general, after you create a DataTable such as `dt` you can do something like this to add data and bind it to a listview:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Fname");
dt.Columns.Add("Lname");
DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
r.ItemArray= new object[] {"mehdi","nine"};
dt.Rows.Add(r);
ListView1.DataSource=dt;
ListView1.DataBind();
```